# Run a command on start up, please

Tags: command-line, keyboard, keyboard-layout, startup

I install Ubuntu on my notebook bought in USA but I'm from Brazil, the problem is, because of the keyboard model, I have to run this command every time I turn on my system:

"setxkbmap -model abnt2 -layout br -variant abnt2"

How can I turn this process automatic, or maybe install a keyboard model. Sorry for bad enlgish.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to set it up as a systemd service:

1. Create a `.service` file, which, once enabled, will be run by systemd upon booting.  In a text editor, create a file called `mykeyboard.service` and include the following (change the `path/to/` part with the actual path to your script):

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=MyKeyboard service

   [Service]
   ExecStart=setxkbmap -model abnt2 -layout br -variant abnt2

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```
2. Place your new `.service` file in the directory `/etc/systemd/system/`
3. To run and have it run on boot, you would use `sudo systemctl enable --now mykeyboard`

That should do it!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running a command at each startup, you'd better save those settings persistently. Open `/etc/default/keyboard` for editing and give it this contents:

```
XKBLAYOUT="br"
BACKSPACE="guess"
XKBVARIANT="abnt2"
XKBMODEL="abnt2"
```